# Tweak the loop for translation

Tags: translation, localization

I am building a custom solution that would be bilingual in English and French. I want to store the French content, title,... in custom metas by adding META BOXES to the edit screen. This part is fine, I can  take care of it without a probalem.

Now,

I can detect the language of the user by using  `substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);` no big deal here either.

Now, depending on the user's language I want the loop to server either the main content ( you know `the_content()` or `the_title()`,... )  or the translated version by running some filter.

Which code would I have to code in the plugin or functions.php ?

Comment: I hate doing this, but I would recommend using a multi language plugin for this job, something like polylang. Basically what you are asking here is to code a plugin for you, which that does not go well here.

Comment: I am not asking for a plugin. I am a plugin developer myself. I just want to slightly filter the_content and the_title by passing the language parameters. Anyways, I have an idea but thlugh someone might have done it already.